# Java enum ordinal in JNI

Tags: java, c++, enums, java-native-interface

I have a java-enum:

```
puclic enum TestSet{
  TEST_COLOR,
  TEST_SKEW,
  TEST_ANGLE;
}
```

Now what I'd like to have is the possibility to write code in my c++ code like this:

```
Test::Test(){
 bool foo [5];

 ....
 ....
 foo[TestSet.TEST_COLOR] = true;
 foo[TestSet.TEST_SKEW]  = false;

 ....
 .....

}
```

I'm asking for **ordinal** because I want the index of the enum field in c++ and in java by .ordinal().

I'm aware of that I could pass the enum and access the fields by string. 
 something like this :

```
jclass clSTATUS    = env->FindClass("TestSet");
jfieldID fidTEST_COLOR    = env->GetStaticFieldID(clSTATUS , "TEST_COLOR", TestSet;");
jobject STATUS_ONE = env->GetStaticObjectField(clSTATUS, fidONE);
```

But it would be far more convenient to have something like the code I proposed. Is this possible somehow? I could also copy the java enum into c++ but then I have to maintain two files.

Answer (score 0):

If you run `javah` on the `enum` class itself it will generate a .h file with `#define` statements for all the ordinal values.

Comment: by default I couldn't achieve this with my javah. But I think you came up with this solution in another forum [here](https://community.oracle.com/thread/2166006). However, I'd need to "tune" my enum java with the additional information in order to get the defines. I'd rather like something similar to a real enum in c++ than defines.

Comment: You get what it gives you.